# How to return a struct by value in Rust?

Tags: rust

I'm learning Rust and failed on the first steps already... I have the next function:

```
use std::env;
use std::path::Path;

fn get_path() -> Path {
    let args: Vec<String> = env::args().collect();
    assert!(!args.is_empty(), "Target path is required!");
    let path = Path::new(&args[0]);
    assert!(path.exists(), "Target path doesn't exist!");
    assert!(path.is_dir(), "Target path is not a directory!");
    return path;
}
```

It's very simple function but `path` is a reference and I can't get how can I return `Path` object from function by value? Or how to return a reference that will be alive in outer function context?

**P.S.** I looked for similar question but I didn't get it, unfortunately.

Comment: [The documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/path/struct.Path.html): "[`Path`] is an *unsized* type, meaning that it must always be used behind a pointer like `&` or [`Box`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/boxed/struct.Box.html). For an owned version of this type, see [`PathBuf`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/path/struct.PathBuf.html)."

Comment: The `assert!()` macro, or panicking more generally, are meant to handle programming errors, while a directory not existing is a runtime error. Runtime errors are better handled by returning a `Result`.

Comment: @SvenMarnach, thank you, I'll fix it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Strictly speaking, `Path` is not a reference, it is rather an unsized type which can only exist *behind* a reference, and indeed [`Path::new` returns `&Path` not `Path`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/path/struct.Path.html#method.new). Which is therefore incompatible with the `-> Path` you've annotated your function with.

These are in fact the two things the compile error tells you, and you really want to give people compilation errors (or reproduction cases) when posting Rust code as the errors are extremely informative once you've gotten used to them:

```
error[E0277]: the size for values of type `[u8]` cannot be known at compilation time
 --> src/lib.rs:4:18
  |
4 | fn get_path() -> Path {
  |                  ^^^^ borrow the `Path` instead
  |
```

says that you're returning an unsized type which is not allowed), and

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/lib.rs:10:12
   |
4  | fn get_path() -> Path {
   |                  ---- expected `std::path::Path` because of return type
...
10 |     return path;
   |            ^^^^ expected struct `std::path::Path`, found `&std::path::Path`
```

explains that the type you want to return doesn't match the type of the value you're returning.

Anyway as [the official documentation for `Path` notes](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/path/struct.Path.html), the owned / structure version of `Path` is [`PathBuf`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/path/struct.PathBuf.html), so you should return that, and convert your `Path` into a `PathBuf`, or really just create a `PathBuf` in the first place, e.g.

```rust
use std::env;
use std::path::PathBuf;

fn get_path() -> PathBuf {
    let args: Vec<String> = env::args().collect();
    assert!(!args.is_empty(), "Target path is required!");
    let path = PathBuf::from(&args[0]);
    assert!(path.exists(), "Target path doesn't exist!");
    assert!(path.is_dir(), "Target path is not a directory!");
    path
}
```

Incidentally,

> ```
> Path::new(&args[0]);
> ```

is probably not what you expect or want: as the documentation for `std::env::args` notes:

> The first element is traditionally the path of the executable

and this is not an area where Rust has seen fit to diverge from the underlying system.

You likely want `args[1]` instead, or to use a higher-level args-parsing API.

And an other aside related to Sven Marnach's comment to your question: calling `path.exists` then `path.is_dir` requires fetching the metadata twice (I don't think Rust caches this information). The efficienty aspect is probably not primordial here but you may still want to explicitly use `Path::metadata`, followed by asking *that* if `is_dir` (`Path::metadata` will return an `Err` if the path is not to a valid on-disk thing).

Comment: And instead of collecting `env::args()` into a vector and then indexing into the vector, you may want to do `env::args().nth(1)` instead.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer, I got my mistakes.